# PHP for iPad, or other solutions

Tags: php, ipad, webserver

Here's a tricky one.

I'm developing a web app for iPads that will be installed as kiosks. The app is essentially a quiz. Wont need to store data in a database, but will need to process data from 1 page to another page (from questions page to results page).

Original solution was simple PHP. I have now been informed that wi-fi/3g will be unavailable to the kiosks, so they wont have access to the webserver w/ php that has been working like a charm. App needs to be browser-based.

Looked around for solutions for installing PHP on iPad, like PHPPOD from Cydia, but unsure if that is even an option for iPad...and we wont be jailbreaking them. Can this even be done w/o php?

Comment: It seems to me like the answer to the will be *"No"* and you need to reconsider whether you app has to be browser based. But I won't put that as an answer in case someone else has any bright ideas...

Comment: There's only one app I'm aware of that runs PHP on the iPad: [Kodiak](https://itunes.apple.com/app/kodiak-php/id542685332)

Answer (score 2):

If you won't be jailbreaking them, trying to get a working PHP interpreter on them might not be impossible, but it'll probably be at the very least annoyingly difficult (and it's unlikely Apple would approve random PHP interpreters in their app store).

I'd suggest trying to port the app to Javascript instead. If it's just a simple questions -> results flow, writing a basic Javascript web app with jQuery to help out if need be shouldn't be too painful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not jailbreaking them, then you will NOT be able to get any un-approved apps onto them. Apple does NOT want you to bypass the app store, because they want their 30% cut. Installing a PHP interpreter on an iphone/ipad would allow you to build apps outside of Apple's control - this is THE main reason why Flash will never been on an iphone - it's not just for playing movies, it's actually a pretty full runtime environment.

You could try using HTML5 local storage, or use the native SQLlite database in iOS.

Comment: Er, the OP specifically mentions they *don't* need to store data in a database.

Comment: Yes, but they're doing it as a webapp, and have no access to a webserver, so they'll need SOME method to store data locally.

Comment: Why? They didn't necessarily say that the webapp had any need for persistent data; for instance, a calculator can be a webapp, but it doesn't have to save anything for when you come back next week?

Answer (score 0):

Without wifi/3G you would need local storage won't you? For this you need not jailbreak your iPad & force it to work through PHP. You could do that following -

1. Jailbreak the app & maybe try to get your PHP solution working on iPad.
2. Build a native app with local storage (using [sqlite or core data](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)) & handle the display through [**UIWebView**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
3. Build a [HTML5 app with local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is easy to do nowadays, again UIWebView would be used.
4. As Amber suggests, you could build all your quizzing logic in javascript, but I am concerned here as to where you'll store data. You need to refer to point 3.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Er, the OP specifically mentions they *don't* need to store data in a database.

Comment: i am basing on `I have now been informed that wi-fi/3g will be unavailable to the kiosks`. Without internet, how would one get the initial set of questions?

Comment: Hardcoded into the app? That is likely how the original app was implemented anyway.

Comment: yeah, but with a large set of questions, the browser can get non-responsive (since its in Javascript & needs to load all during app start). That's what databases are for. Just a simple table in sqlite would make the user experience a lote better, a.k.a local storage...

Comment: Thanks Amber. I think I'll have to go the JS route. I wont need to store data and the app will not have a large number of questions. They will be hardcoded into the app b/c aforementioned lack of wi-fi/3g. It's a silly little project with major constraints. I think the calculator comparison was apt!