# Is it possible to run a magento installation locally on an ipad?

Tags: php, database, ipad, magento, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP for iPad, or other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389741/php-for-ipad-or-other-solutions)

We have a trade show coming up and the internet service is never great.  Is it possible to set up a magento store to run locally on an ipad?

Comment: How do yo uplan on processing transactions if you are running it offline?

Comment: what about cell phone coverage ? odd for a trade show in any field theses days not to have wi-fi and wired net access- its more important than electricity to most.

Comment: its just like a demo thing - we just launched a new site, no transactions.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389741/php-for-ipad-or-other-solutions

Comment: how about running wget to mirror the site, and using the ipad browser to 'surf' the locally stored copy ?

Answer (score 1):

Not without jailbreaking your device and a tremendous amount of hacking.  There are people who have reportedly run Apache, PHP, MySQL on iOS.  But getting your configuration right to run Magento is probably going to be very challenging prospect.  Here is a link to some discussion on MacRumours forum about this subject.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=962699

Comment: what about somehow hosting the site locally off a pc laptop, then connecting via wifi with the ipads? im not hardware limited here - we just are probably not going to have a good 3/4g connection.

Comment: Sure, but where are you going to get connectivity for your laptop?  If it is just from some wifi at the show, you might as well use that wifi directly on your iPad.  You don't need cellular.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set it up on a laptop and do some sort of adhoc wireless networking with it.  I think that might be easier than the whole jailbreaking route.

Answer (score 0):

Ipad's just a giant iPhone. You don't have the components there to do what you want (there's no app for that). Now if you had a Mac laptop laying around, you could set up a MAMP system and do everything you want.

You could then probably connect the iPad(s) via wireless and demo what you want all day off that setup.